# How to get the file name from an URI got from ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent?

Tags: java, android, uri

I used a ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent to let the user choose a song from his library, then it is returned in the `onActivityResult()` method as an URI.

I need to get the name of the song.

I tried with:

```
Uri song; //got from onActivityResult

String songName = song.getLastPathSegment();
```

and with:

```
Uri song; //got from onActivityResult

File file = new File(song.getPath());
String songName = file.getName();
```

in both cases the `songName`String looks like this:

```
// audio:9980
```

while I'm expecting something like:

```
// Walk on the wild side.mp3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get the name of the file.

It is not a file. It is a `Uri`, just like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615264/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-an-uri-got-from-action-get-content-intent` is a URI. `how-to-get-the-file-name-from-an-uri-got-from-action-get-content-intent` is not a filename.

> What am I doing wrong?

You are assuming that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` gives you a file.

You are welcome to use a `ContentResolver` to `query()` for the `OpenableColumns` and ask for the `DISPLAY_NAME`. I demonstrate that in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/Documents/Consumer). However, please understand that you are getting a display name, and it is up to the app that the user chooses to handle `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` what the "display name" actually is. It *might* be a filename, but it does not have to be.

Comment: I actually explained it wrong in the question. I will edit it right now. I know I'm not working with a file but with an Uri and I know the difference between them. Could you post the piece of code where you get the name? Thank you for the fast answer

Comment: @Daniele: See [these lines from the sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.5/Documents/Consumer/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/documents/consumer/ConsumerFragment.java#L91-L142) where I use a `CursorLoader` to retrieve the `OpenableColumns`.